# Is there any web service to make phone calls like Google 2-step verification?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any web service that provides something to make phone calls?

Let say I want to build one site where people can make phonepranks. I enter the number of my friend and when I submit the form, it calls him with a message like "7 days".

Or like google does with its 2-step verification. When you don't receive a message google gives you the option to call you and give the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it. It's called [hoiio](http://developer.hoiio.com/) and it works almost on every country. It's affordable and easy to implement.

The other options were [tropo](https://www.tropo.com/), [pilvo](http://www.plivo.org/) ( I couldn't make them work) amd [twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) (it doesn't work for my country).